# How to provide "Login Using Facebook" for external users when using "Facebook Login For Business" product?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've a login page where I provide external users with an option "Login Using Facebook". The Meta App has a type "Business" & using the product "Facebook Login For Business". I want to able to authenticate the users & then redirect them to "Facebook Messenger URL (https://m.me)". However, whenever I try to log in the user, the login pop-up window becomes a blank white screen after entering the user's credentials. I'm getting the below error when authenticating the user.

```
ErrorUtils caught an error:

Minified invariant #21945; 

Subsequent non-fatal errors won't be logged; see https://fburl.com/debugjs.
```

However, when I switch to the product "Facebook Login", I'm able to authenticate the external user just fine without any issue.
So, my question is how can I authenticate external users when using "Facebook Login For Business" or is it even possible to authenticate external users when using "Facebook Login For Business"?

[Blank screen & console error on user authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FabqM.png)

Here's my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Messenger | Demo</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CDN -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="row justify-content-center my-5 py-5">
        <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
            <div class="fb-login-button" data-width="" data-size="large" data-button-type="" data-layout=""
                data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="true" onlogin="redirectToMessenger"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Meta Scripts -->
    <script>
        function redirectToMessenger() {
            FB.login(
                function(response) {
                    if (response.status !== 'connected' || !response.authResponse) {
                        console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
                        return;
                    }

                    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');

                    FB.api('/me', {
                        fields: 'name, email'
                    }, function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    });

                    window.location = 'http://m.me/<id>';
                },
                {
                    // scope:          "public_profile,email",
                    // return_scopes:  true,
                    // config_id:      "<config-id>"
                }
            );
        }

        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
                appId:      '<app-id>',
                cookie:     true,
                xfbml:      true,
                version:    'v19.0',
            });
        };
    </script>
    <script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```